# How to update the renewed ssl certificates of schema registry server runtime?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, certificate, confluent-schema-registry

We are running a schema registry server instance with ssl turned ON. The certificates have a defined lifetime. And we have a renewed certificate with extended durations and would like to update it to the running schema registry server. there seems to be no script like dynamic configs in kafka to update configs in runtime without restarting the server.

Is there any other work arounds  or scripts which we are not aware of or restarting the server with the renewed certificates is the only way to update the certificates ?